# iOS app doesn't start automatically when using Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin

Probably a simple settings question, but I can't seem to find the setting. Running Xamarin Studio 3 with an iOS project. When I hit Run (the play symbol), the app builds and deploys. But the app doesn't start and I have to start it manually. It's the same on three phones and two iPads so it must be a setting in Xamarin Studio or on the Mac itself.

The message is as follows:

"Waiting for debugger to connect... The application has been build and uploaded, or is already up to date".

I then manually have to start the app, the debugger connects and all is well. Not a bug problem, but something I would like to know the cause of. :)

Thanks

Johan

Comment: Try to toggle USB Debugging (in Xamarin Studio's options, find the "Projects/Debugger/iOS Debugger" page and toggle the "Debug iOS devices over WiFi instead of over USB" checkbox)

Comment: Sorry, didn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: Is this happening in Both Debug and Release mode?

Comment: Can you get the device log (in Xamarin Studio's View->Pads->iOS Device Log) and see what's printed when Xamarin Studio tries to launch the app?

Comment: In both Debug and Release. Nothing in the logs.

Answer (score 17):

[image]

There is a new type of issue which looks exactly the same. Just in case, here is a solution which worked very well for me in the past.

**Problem:**

Can't debug. It says wrong "Provisioning profile"!

**What you are doing:**

You are keep changing "configuration", "platform", "identity" and "Provisioning profile" using "iOS Bundle
Profile" tab, because the issue says something about a wrong Provisioning profile, but nothing really helps.

**What is really happening:**

Nothing. For some reason Xamarin extension doesn't save changes to the project file

**Solution:**

Find your *.csproj file and open it in the text editor (I hope you are using notepad++). Find and delete `<CodesignKey>` and `<CodesignProvision>` sections. Save. Reload this solution in a Visual Studio and if you are satisfied with the result - hit "Like" button

Comment: I don't see <CodesigKey> and <CodesignProvision> and I get the same error. Any other workaround?

Comment: @LohithKorupolu if possible try to open this solution using Visual Studio and see what happens. I hate to suggest something like that, but if I was you I would consider to change dev platform from Xamarin to Hybrid (Framework7, Ionic, etc.) Btw, I did it myself and I have no regrets so far. Not everything is perfect in a hybrid world, but I didn't find bugs like that (so far). :-)

Comment: I work with Xamarin.Forms an VS2017. The entries under <CodesignKey> and <CodesignProvision> were wrong. But to delete/correct it has not solved the problem (still the same message).

Comment: I tried but not work. I must delete related certificates and create new everything again. It work.

Answer (score 5):

The solution was simple. I had the wrong provisioning profile under Bundle signing in the project setting. Setting all to Automatic resolved the issue.