# Xamarin for Visual Studio message when trying to deploy to external iPad

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin + Visual Studio 2015 at windows, Visual Studio is able to connect to my remote Mac Pro, I was able to debug iOS.

However, suddenly I'm seeing this error when I try to use simulator, I might did something for android setting but nothing I can remember I did for iOS.

Any helper would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Someone already post same question, my issue was i have to remove **CodesignKey** and **CodesignProvision** from my iOS project file.

[iOS app doesn't start automatically when using Xamarin Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261799/ios-app-doesnt-start-automatically-when-using-xamarin-studio)

Comment: Please don't self-answer duplicate questions.  Instead, flag your question as a duplicate.